# How can I send multiple objects with RubyAmf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache-flex, rubyamf

I'm new to RubyAmf. I noticed that you can send an object with RubyAmf as follows:

```
format.amf { render :amf => @user}
```

Which works fine. But I wasn't sure what to do what when I have two ,or more, objects:

```
@projects = @user.projects
@tasks = @user.tasks
```

How can I can send @projects and @tasks without having to do multiple requests from flex.

Thanks,

Tam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [RubyAMF code](http://github.com/thillerson/rubyamf/blob/master/lib/amf/pure/serializer.rb) there is support array serialization. So the following code should work.

```
@projects = @user.projects
format.amf { render :amf => @projects}
```

If you want to send both `projects` and `tasks` together you can send them back in a hash.

```
format.amf { render :amf =>{:projects => @user.projects, :tasks => @user.tasks} }
```

**Caveat:** I haven't tested this code. I am inferring the functionality based on the gem code.

Comment: Thanks @KandadaBoggu but can I send both @tasks and @projects together? I know I can send @projects array as you mentioned